# The purpose of .to() method

Tags: java, android

I was following a tutorial and came across a .to() method that gets used a few times. I was wanting to know what its purpose is and how it works. I have tried to find an answer via google but didn't get the answer i was looking for. I have attached a piece of my code below:

```
public void updateUnitTextFieldUsingTsp(double doubleToConvert, Quantity.Unit currentUnit,
                                        Quantity.Unit preferredUnit, TextView targetTextView){


    Quantity currentQuantitySelected = new Quantity(doubleToConvert, currentUnit);

    String tempTextViewText = currentQuantitySelected.to(Quantity.Unit.tsp).to(preferredUnit)
            .toString();

    targetTextView.setText(tempTextViewText);

}
```

All help is appreciated.

EDIT:

I've added in some more code below which includes my full Main Activity and my Quantity class:

Quantity class:

```
public class Quantity {

final double value;
final Unit unit;

public static enum Unit{

    tsp(1.0d), tbs(0.3333d), cups(0.0208d), oz(0.1666d), pint(0.0104d),
    quart(0.0052d), gallon(0.0013d), pound(0.0125d), ml(4.9289d), liter(0.0049d),
    mg(5687.5d), kg(0.0057d);

    final static Unit baseUnit = tsp;

    final double byBaseUnit;


    private Unit(double inTsp){
        this.byBaseUnit = inTsp;

    }

    public double toBaseUnit(double value){

        return value / byBaseUnit;

    }

    public double fromBaseUnit(double value){

        return value * byBaseUnit;
    }


}

public Quantity(double value, Unit unit){
    super();
    this.value = value;
    this.unit = unit;

}

public Quantity to(Unit newUnit){

    Unit oldUnit = this.unit;
    return new Quantity(newUnit.fromBaseUnit(oldUnit.toBaseUnit(value)), newUnit);


}

@Override
public String toString(){

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0000");
    return df.format(value) + " " + unit.name();

}
```

}

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Spinner unitTypeSpinner;
private EditText amountTextView;

TextView teaspoonTextview, tablespoonTextview, cupTextView, ounceTextView,
         pintTextView, quartTextView, gallonTextView, poundTextView,
         milliliterTextView, literTextview, miligramTextView, kilogramTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addItemsToUnitTypeSpinner();

    addListnerToUnitTypeSpinner();

    amountTextView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount_text_view);

    initializeTextViews();

}

public void initializeTextViews(){
    teaspoonTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tsp_text_view);
    tablespoonTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tbs_text_view);
    cupTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cup_text_view);
    ounceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oz_text_view);
    pintTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pint_text_view);
    quartTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quart_text_view);
    gallonTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gallon_text_view);
    poundTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pound_text_view);
    milliliterTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ml_text_view);
    literTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.liter_text_view);
    miligramTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mg_text_view);
    kilogramTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kg_text_view);
}

private void addItemsToUnitTypeSpinner(){
    unitTypeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.unit_type_spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> unitTypeSpinnerAdapter =
            ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.conversion_types,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    unitTypeSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    unitTypeSpinner.setAdapter(unitTypeSpinnerAdapter);
}

public void addListnerToUnitTypeSpinner(){
    unitTypeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.unit_type_spinner);

    unitTypeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String itemSelectedInSpinner =
                    parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            checkIfConvertingFromTsp(itemSelectedInSpinner);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            //TODO maybe something here later

        }
    });
}

public void checkIfConvertingFromTsp(String currentUnit) {
    if (currentUnit.equals("teaspoon")) {

        updateUnitTypesUsingTsp(Quantity.Unit.tsp);

    } else {

        if (currentUnit.equals("tabspoon")) {

            updateUnitTypesUsingOther(Quantity.Unit.tbs);

        } else if (currentUnit.equals("cup")) {

            updateUnitTypesUsingOther(Quantity.Unit.cups);
        } else if (currentUnit.equals("ounce")) {

            updateUnitTypesUsingOther(Quantity.Unit.oz);
        } else if (currentUnit.equals("pint")) {

            updateUnitTypesUsingOther(Quantity.Unit.pint);
        } else if (currentUnit.equals("quart")) {

            updateUnitTypesUsingOther(Quantity.Unit.quart);
        } else if (currentUnit.equals(("gallon"))) {

            updateUnitTypesUsingOther(Quantity.Unit.gallon);
        } else if (currentUnit.equals("pound")) {

            updateUnitTypesUsingOther(Quantity.Unit.pound);
        } else if (currentUnit.equals("milliliter")) {

            updateUnitTypesUsingOther(Quantity.Unit.ml);
        } else if (currentUnit.equals("liter")) {

            updateUnitTypesUsingOther(Quantity.Unit.liter);
        } else if (currentUnit.equals("milligram")) {

            updateUnitTypesUsingOther(Quantity.Unit.mg);
        } else {

            updateUnitTypesUsingOther(Quantity.Unit.kg);
        }
    }
}


    public void updateUnitTypesUsingTsp(Quantity.Unit currentUnit){

    double doubleToConvert = Double.parseDouble(amountTextView.getText().toString());

    String teaspoonValueAndUnit = doubleToConvert + " tsp";

    teaspoonTextview.setText(teaspoonValueAndUnit);

    updateUnitTextFieldUsingTsp(doubleToConvert, Quantity.Unit.tbs, tablespoonTextview);
    updateUnitTextFieldUsingTsp(doubleToConvert, Quantity.Unit.cups, cupTextView);
    updateUnitTextFieldUsingTsp(doubleToConvert, Quantity.Unit.oz, ounceTextView);
    updateUnitTextFieldUsingTsp(doubleToConvert, Quantity.Unit.pint, pintTextView);
    updateUnitTextFieldUsingTsp(doubleToConvert, Quantity.Unit.quart, quartTextView);
    updateUnitTextFieldUsingTsp(doubleToConvert, Quantity.Unit.gallon, gallonTextView);
    updateUnitTextFieldUsingTsp(doubleToConvert, Quantity.Unit.pound, poundTextView);
    updateUnitTextFieldUsingTsp(doubleToConvert, Quantity.Unit.ml, milliliterTextView);
    updateUnitTextFieldUsingTsp(doubleToConvert, Quantity.Unit.liter, literTextview);
    updateUnitTextFieldUsingTsp(doubleToConvert, Quantity.Unit.mg, miligramTextView);
    updateUnitTextFieldUsingTsp(doubleToConvert, Quantity.Unit.kg, kilogramTextView);
}

public void updateUnitTextFieldUsingTsp(double doubleToConvert, Quantity.Unit unitConvertingTo,
                                        TextView theTextView){

    Quantity unitQuantity = new Quantity(doubleToConvert, Quantity.Unit.tsp);

    String temptUnit = unitQuantity.to(unitConvertingTo).toString();
    theTextView.setText(temptUnit);

}

public void updateUnitTypesUsingOther(Quantity.Unit currentUnit){

    double doubleToConvert = Double.parseDouble(amountTextView.getText().toString());

    Quantity currentQuantitySelected = new Quantity(doubleToConvert, currentUnit);

    String valueInTeaspoons = currentQuantitySelected.to(Quantity.Unit.tsp).toString();

    teaspoonTextview.setText(valueInTeaspoons);

    updateUnitTextFieldUsingTsp(doubleToConvert, currentUnit, Quantity.Unit.tbs,
            tablespoonTextview);

    updateUnitTextFieldUsingTsp(doubleToConvert, currentUnit, Quantity.Unit.cups,
            cupTextView);

    updateUnitTextFieldUsingTsp(doubleToConvert, currentUnit, Quantity.Unit.oz,
            ounceTextView);

    updateUnitTextFieldUsingTsp(doubleToConvert, currentUnit, Quantity.Unit.pint,
            pintTextView);

    updateUnitTextFieldUsingTsp(doubleToConvert, currentUnit, Quantity.Unit.gallon,
            gallonTextView);

    updateUnitTextFieldUsingTsp(doubleToConvert, currentUnit, Quantity.Unit.pound,
            poundTextView);

    updateUnitTextFieldUsingTsp(doubleToConvert, currentUnit, Quantity.Unit.ml,
            milliliterTextView);

    updateUnitTextFieldUsingTsp(doubleToConvert, currentUnit, Quantity.Unit.liter,
            literTextview);

    updateUnitTextFieldUsingTsp(doubleToConvert, currentUnit, Quantity.Unit.mg,
            miligramTextView);

    updateUnitTextFieldUsingTsp(doubleToConvert, currentUnit, Quantity.Unit.kg,
            kilogramTextView);

    if(currentUnit.name().equals(currentQuantitySelected.unit.name())){

        String currentUnitTextViewText = doubleToConvert + " " +
                currentQuantitySelected.unit.name();

        String currentTextViewName = currentQuantitySelected.unit.name() + " _text_view";

        int currentId = getResources().getIdentifier(currentTextViewName, "id",
                MainActivity.this.getPackageName());

        TextView currentTextView = (TextView) findViewById(currentId);

        currentTextView.setText(currentUnitTextViewText);

    }

}

public void updateUnitTextFieldUsingTsp(double doubleToConvert, Quantity.Unit currentUnit,
                                        Quantity.Unit preferredUnit, TextView targetTextView){


    Quantity currentQuantitySelected = new Quantity(doubleToConvert, currentUnit);

    String tempTextViewText = currentQuantitySelected.to(Quantity.Unit.tsp).to(preferredUnit)
            .toString();

    targetTextView.setText(tempTextViewText);

}
```

I was following a tutorial to create an app that converts a quantity in a unit to another unit (unit converter).

Comment: Seems to be a method to change the current unit for the given quantity object. However, this question cannot really be answered without further information, since there is no reference to a class definition or documentation.

Comment: You should really provide a link to the tutorial because without context this is just jarble

Comment: The link is at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mjjuk3Fac84&list=PLGLfVvz_LVvSPjWpLPFEfOCbezi6vATIh&index=10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `Quantity` consists of a number and a unit. The `Unit` basically is a factor. What is called the base unit in the code is the unit with the factor 1. So the methods `toBaseUnit` and `fromBaseUnit` in the `Unit` class are used to convert a number from the given unit to the base unit and vice versa. The purpose of the `.to()` method is to create a new `Quantity` object that represents the same quantity as the old one. However, the new `Quantity` object should use the `newUnit` to store the quantity. To make it more clear, the following equality (written in pseudocode) should be true:

```
oldQ.value * oldQ.unit.byBaseUnit == newQ.value * newQ.unit.byBaseUnit
```

`oldQ` and `newQ` represent the old and new quantity objects.

So in your code above you can replace the line ...

```
String tempTextViewText = currentQuantitySelected
        .to(Quantity.Unit.tsp)
        .to(preferredUnit)
        .toString();
```

... by this code ...

```
String tempTextViewText = currentQuantitySelected
        .to(preferredUnit)
        .toString();
```

... because the `to()` method already handles the conversion from the old unit to the base unit and then to the `preferredUnit`. The `to()` method does not actually change the quantity, but its representation.